# get names, id and data of an unknown number of columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

if I have a table with one row of data how do I 'like' transpose it and get the data it has??

```
item1 item2 item3  item4...  itemn
  101   102   103    104...      n
```

How do I get something like

```
name  colid  value
item1     1    101
item2     2    102
item3     3    103
item4     4    104
...
itemn     n      n
```

@dzibul answer something similar, but the missing part is how to retrieve the data???

```
select name, colorder from syscolumns where id = (select id from sysobjects where name = [tablename])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Working sample

```
create table onerowdata(item1 int, item2 int, item3 int, dt datetime, itemn varchar(100));
insert onerowdata select 101, 102, 103, getdate(), 'TEST DATA';

declare @tbl sysname set @tbl = 'onerowdata'
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = isnull(@sql+' union all ','')
    + 'select '
    + quotename(column_name, '''') + ' name,'
    + RIGHT(ORDINAL_POSITION,12) + ' colid,'
    + 'convert(varchar(max),' + quotename(column_name) + ') value'
    + ' from ' + quotename(@tbl)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = @tbl
order by ORDINAL_POSITION
select @sql = @sql + ' order by 2'
--print @sql
exec (@sql)
```